# Android, Custom permission granted before creation

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm trying to use a custom permission created by another application (**Bazaar**) in my app (It's a permission to use a market `com.farsitel.bazaar.permission.PAY_THROUGH_BAZAAR`). Normally it works right.

But if **Bazaar** is installed after my application. My app won't get the custom permissions (Which are created by **Bazaar**) and throws exception. I want to know If anybody else has faced a similar problem and what solutions do you have to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a desired behaviour.

In the textbook, Android Security Internals: An In-Depth Guide to Android's Security Architecture by [Nikolay Elenkov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/242930/nikolay-elenkov)(2014) said:

> The system can only grant a permission that it knows about, which
> means that applications that define custom permissions need to be
> installed before the applications that make use of those permissions
> are installed. If an application requests a permission unknown to the
> system, it is ignored and not granted.

BTW, permissions are assigned to each application at the install time by PackageManager, it maintains some information of installed packages, such as package name, version and permissions, these info are stored in `/data/system/packages.xml`. If you want to query all permissions on device, you can try `pm list permissions`.